# How do I apply pixel shader to specific sprite in XNA 4.0 in a spritesort FrontToBack?

Tags: xna, sprites, isometric

I have a set of sprite drawn in FrontToBack sortmode. In XNA 4.0, the effect must be as an input argument of `Begin()` function of `SpriteBatch`. However, If I reinvoke the function, then the sprite sorting is lost. Therefore, I have to find a way to implement the pixel shader within the `Begin()` and `End()` for specific texture drawn. I tried to use `effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply(),` but no pixel was shaded when I invoke this. On the other hand, if I put effect as an argument, then all of the sprites would be effected. Therefore, is there any convenient way to approach this?

By the way, what I am trying to do is to provide an overlay on an isometric tile using some kind of masking. Therefore, I want to draw such masking and programmatically change it to optional color.

Something like this (from final fantasy tactics):

[image]

I am not sure if pixel shader is the right way to approach it, but then I have to tackle the fact that I want to be able to specify optional color dynamically. Other than that, I really want it to animate, which I might approach this by creating several grayscale animated masking and saturate it using pixel shader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing effects and effect parameters in a single batch doesn't work unless if you're using the SpriteSortMode.Immediate. This happens because the sprite batch waits until you call spriteBatch.End() before starting the drawing.

It seems like you would like to use the spritebatch because you want to sort the sprites before drawing. If you manually sort the sprites and then draw them all using SortMode.Immediate you  can use effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply() anywhere between .Begin() and .End().

Comment: So you suggest me to manually sort all the sprite without relying on spritebatch functionality. I want to know if there is any performance penalty by implementing my own sorting code. Wouldn't that means that I have to invoke several hundred of Begin()/End()? Will that affect the performance?

Comment: Sorting is 'cheap' and will always be O(n log n) wether you do it or the SB does it. Also you will only need one Begin()/End() since in immediate mode you can change the shaders and shader args anywhere between Begin() and Ed(). There will be a performance penalty for using immediate mode though, since it doesn't batch.

Answer (score 1):

This link might help you out with the issue:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb313868(v=xnagamestudio.31).aspx